# ASP.NET MVC 3 Pattern for dynamic validation attributes including client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, validation

My validation requirements for a the fields in a form are contained in an external table so that they can be updated without altering and rebuilding the code.

I have approximatley 100 fields with a mixture of validation requirements - range, required, regular expression and dependency on other fields. One example is date range validation. A date of birth field requires a date range which is between -10 years and -50 years of the current date.

I have read around the subject but have not identified a pattern for the complete solution.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with MVC 3 and Entity Framework.

Any help with this would be gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are looking for a client-side validation solution using jQuery, I might be able to help you - however, I will have to ask my boss as I wrote the validator plugin at work, which means its his property.

Comment: Hi Jeff  - thanks for the offer however the jQuery is OK. What I'm really after is the MVC parts for creating dynamic validation attributes and then using this as unobtrusive jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: What are you validating? String values?

Comment: Thanks. See list above - esentially everything as I'm trying to build a table driven general validation model. Cheers Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple level I think you can still use the built-in Data-Annotations validation attributes to does the validation and for that you should map the validation rules stored in the table to the attributes.

I think all you have to do is create a custom model validation provider by inheriting the class `ModelValidatorProvider`. This class contains a single method called `GetValidators` that returns the collection validators for that model.

You have to implement the `GetValidators` method and in there you have to make a database call to get the validation rules for the model from the database (or from cache?) and convert them into `ModelValidator`s. You could still use the built-in `DataAnnotationsModelValidator` to do the validations.

I would suggest you to look into the source code of `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` that will give you all the information. In that class what they are doing is basically iterating all the validation attributes applied to the model properties and converting them into `ModelValidator`s through adapters and factories. In your case instead of attributes they are stored as records in tables and I don't think much work will be there.

Comment: Thank you Mark - a very useful overview.

Comment: Thanks Mark, following your sugestions I found the following (see next comment)

Comment: (continued) [link](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2011/08/dataannotations-mvc3-unobtrusive-validations/) which describes exactly what to do.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on this subject http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/9/creating_custom_modelvalidatorprovider